# Prove that if $X_n\stackrel{d}\to X$ and $X_n\stackrel{d}\to Y$ then $X\stackrel{d}=Y$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Prove that if $X_n\stackrel{d}\to X$ and $X_n\stackrel{d}\to Y$ then $X\stackrel{d}=Y$.

Okey. I know that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} F_{X_n}(t)=F_X(t)$$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} F_{X_n}(t)=F_Y(t)$$ So $$\lim_{n \to \infty} F_{X_n}(t)=F_X(t)=F_Y(t)$$

So this implies that $$X\stackrel{d}=Y$$ right?

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what is $F$?

Comment: $F$ is cumulative distribution function. Isnt it a conventional notation for that?

Comment: Damn! I should power of my phone, when I am drunken!

Comment: Note that $\lim_{n \to \infty} F_{X_n}(t) = F_X(t)$ does not hold for all $t$, but only for those $t$ which have an additional property.

Comment: You mean $F(t)$ is continuous at $t$?